# while loop execution with Tupled List c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, while-loop, tuples

I have this code for insertion of data into database. I have created a tupled List of `<string, double, string[]>` and add elements to List inside a nested while loop. Here is the code....

```
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\research_fields.txt");


            Program p = new Program();

            var dd = new List<Tuple<string, double, string>>();

            //string document = "The trie data structure has many properties which make it especially attractive for representing large files of data. These properties include fast retrieval time, quick unsuccessful search determination, and finding the longest match to a given identifier. The main drawback is the space requirement. In this paper the concept of trie compaction is formalized. An exact algorithm for optimal trie compaction and three algorithms for approximate trie compaction are given, and an analysis of the three algorithms is done. The analysis indicate that for actual tries, reductions of around 70 percent in the space required by the uncompacted trie can be expected. The quality of the compaction is shown to be insensitive to the number of nodes, while a more relevant parameter is the alphabet size of the key.";

            //string[] document = get_Abstract();
            string line;
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KHIZER;Initial Catalog=subset_aminer;Integrated Security=True");

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand query = con.CreateCommand();
                query.CommandText = "select p_abstract from sub_aminer_paper where pid between 1 and 500 and DATALENGTH(p_abstract) != 0";

                SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

                string summary = null;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    summary = reader["p_abstract"].ToString();

                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        dd.Add(Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, summary), summary));
                    }

                    var top_value = dd.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (top_value != null)
                    {
                        // look up record using top_value.Item3, and then store top_value.Item1
                        var abstrct = top_value.Item3.ToString();
                        var r_field = top_value.Item1.ToString();

                        write_To_Database(abstrct, r_field);
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
 }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");

            }
```

I have debugged it in visual studio 2013 using c#, I have seen the statement that is inside the inner while loop i.e. `dd.Add(Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, summary), summary));` executes only once while it should be executes 22 times as `reader.Read()` has a length 22 documents.
I have checked it by taking only single `string document` shown as `//comment` in code and it works fine but not with reading documents from database.
Not getting why is it so. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Beeecaaause... `file.ReadLine()` returns null?

Comment: you do not see any exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get inside `while` loop, your `line = file.ReadLine()) != null` should be true. If you only get there once, I suspect you have only one line in your file, therefore, no matter how many elements your `document` array has, code inside `while` will execute only once.

Overall, however, your `while` loop code doesn't make much sense to me. You are going to read all you text from the file in your first iteration of `for` and then `while` loop will be skipped forever. If it's your intention to read all lines exactly once, move `while` before the `for`.

To further improve your code look up [ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines(v=vs.110).aspx) and [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) pages.

And to find a max value in the colleciton instead of

```
var top_value = dd.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();
```

use [Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302925(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var top_value = dd.Max(x => x.Item2);
```

**Update**:

```
var lines =  System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\research_fields.txt");
 while (reader.Read())
{
    summary = reader["p_abstract"].ToString();
    dd.AddRange(lines
        .Select( line => 
            Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, summary), summary)
        )
    ); 
    // rest of your stuff
}
```